# k8s api coreV1 does not have requests.cpu for ResourceQuotas

Tags: kubernetes

this is my very first question here :)

I am trying to write something in Go which for the moment is just getting ResourceQuotas. While testing I noticed that when importing k8s.io/api/core/v1 like this:

```
coreV1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
```

And having a variable like this, with the type coming from coreV1:

```
    rq := &coreV1.ResourceQuota{
        TypeMeta:   v1.TypeMeta{},
        ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta{},
        Spec:       coreV1.ResourceQuotaSpec{
            Hard:          map[coreV1.ResourceName]resources.Quantity{},
            Scopes:        []coreV1.ResourceQuotaScope{},
            ScopeSelector: &coreV1.ScopeSelector{},
        },
        Status:     coreV1.ResourceQuotaStatus{},
    }
```

I am not able to e.g. set a ResourceQuota's requests.cpu or limits.cpu, only this is possible:

```
CPULimts := rq.Spec.Hard.Cpu()
fmt.Println(CPULimts)
```

Am I using it wrong or missing something? ResourceQuotas like this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#viewing-and-setting-quotas are working just perfectly fine in many of the clusters I manage.

Do I maybe need to use some other package?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misreading your struct: `Spec.Hard` is a *map* of `corev1.ResourceName` to quotas, where `corev1.ResourceName` is a set of constant strings that includes things like `requests.cpu` (see the [documentation for that package](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#ResourceName)).

So we can write:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/resource"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func main() {
    rq := &corev1.ResourceQuota{
        TypeMeta:   metav1.TypeMeta{},
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{},
        Spec: corev1.ResourceQuotaSpec{
            Hard:          corev1.ResourceList{},
            Scopes:        []corev1.ResourceQuotaScope{},
            ScopeSelector: &corev1.ScopeSelector{},
        },
        Status: corev1.ResourceQuotaStatus{},
    }

    rq.Spec.Hard[corev1.ResourceRequestsCPU] = resource.MustParse("500m")
    rq.Spec.Hard[corev1.ResourceStorage] = resource.MustParse("10G")

    content, err := json.Marshal(rq.Spec)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(string(content))
}
```

Which will output:

```
{
  "hard": {
    "requests.cpu": "500m",
    "storage": "10G"
  },
  "scopeSelector": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot :)

To get the MilliValue of an existing ResourceQuota's requests.cpu I am using e.g.:


`cpuRequests := (rq.Spec.Hard["requests.cpu"])`
`fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(cpuRequests.MilliValue(), 10) + "m")`

Comment: If this helped solve your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.